# Kubernetes (gke) get name of pod network interface

Tags: docker, networking, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm trying to locate a performance issue that might be network related. Therefore I want to inspect all packets entering and leaving a pod.

I'm on kubernetes 1.8.12 on GKE. I ssh to the host and I see the bridge called `cbr0` that sees all the traffic. I also see a ton of interfaces named like `vethdeadbeef@if3`. I assume those are virtual interfaces that are created per container. Where do I look to find out which interface belongs to which container, so I can get all a list of all the interfaces of a pod.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have `cat` available in the container, you can compare the interface index of the containers `eth0` with those of the `veth*` devices on your host. For example:

```
# grep ^ /sys/class/net/vet*/ifindex | grep ":$(docker exec aea243a766c1 cat /sys/class/net/eth0/iflink)"
/sys/class/net/veth1d431c85/ifindex:92
```

`veth1d431c85` is what your are looking for.